# Excel to SQL to get report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have excel sheet with a single column [internet orders] values FN75657, FN83747, FN83673 and so on. I have to query these orders numbers with sql table called [internet orders] with columns [order number],[amount],[document type][date].When I query single orders number in SQL with where cluase [order number] = 'FN75657' I am getting results set with [order number] FN75657 [documnet type] 'order ' , If it is been refunded it will come up as [order number] FN75657-RF-1 and [document type] - 'credit'. I do not want to do one by one as it is taking long time.

```
  SELECT 

   [Internet Order Reference]
  ,[Amount]
  ,[Return Reason Code]
  ,[Shipping Amount]
  ,[Payment Fee Amount Incl_ Tax]
  ,[Document Type]
  ,[DateTime Created]
  ,[Country]
  ,[Email]  
   FROM [vets$ internet Orders]
   where[Country]='united kingdom'and
   [Original Order No_]='FN24680101'
```

[image: this is if i do one by one]

so I have created temp table and inserted excel column and done join, but the porblem is i am unable to get results of refunds, As it is matching with only orders numbers but not getting results of refunds. is there a way to do it in SQL or we have to use SSIS. Thanks in advance.

SQL from comment showing join of temp table and base table.

```
SELECT [Internet Order Reference] 
      ,[Ship-to Name] 
      ,[Amount] 
      ,[Return Reason Code] 
      ,[Shipping Amount] 
      ,[Document Type] 
      ,[DateTime Created] 
FROM [TBW_BI].[dbo].[vets$Internet Orders] as h 
INNER JOIN #temp10b as t 
  on h.[Internet Order Reference] = t.[internet_Order_Reference]
```

Comment: on the join use `[ORIGINAL ORDER NO_] like concat('exceldate.ordernumber','%')`  The issue is the key join needs to be a like and wild card to handle the returns.

Comment: select 
         [Internet Order Reference]
        ,[Ship-to Name]
        ,[Amount]
  ,[Return Reason Code]
  ,[Shipping Amount]
  ,[Document Type]
       ,[DateTime Created]
         from 
          [TBW_BI].[dbo].[vets$Internet Orders] as h
         inner join #temp10b as t
        on h.[Internet Order Reference]=t.[internet_Order_Reference] 
         COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT

Comment: @xQbert could you please help where shall I use key join ans wild card. The above is my join of temp and SQL table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after...

```
SELECT [Internet Order Reference] 
      ,[Ship-to Name] 
      ,[Amount] 
      ,[Return Reason Code] 
      ,[Shipping Amount] 
      ,[Document Type] 
      ,[DateTime Created] 
FROM [TBW_BI].[dbo].[vets$Internet Orders] as h 
INNER JOIN #temp10b as t 
  on h.[Internet Order Reference] like concat(t.[internet_Order_Reference],'*')
```

In essence it says join when 
[internet order reference] of your base table is like the number from excel

EXAMPLE:

'FN75657-RF-1'  like 'FN75657*'

So all combinations of FN75657 would be joined including the returns.  we could be more explicit and use an or... such as...

```
 on ((h.[Internet Order Reference] = t.[internet_Order_Reference])
  OR (h.[Internet Order Reference] like concat(t.[internet_Order_Reference],'-RF-%'))
```

so that only exact matches occur and those which then contain -RF-% suffix to an order.

```
 on ((h.[Internet Order Reference] = t.[internet_Order_Reference])
  OR (h.[Internet Order Reference] like t.[internet_Order_Reference]+'-RF-%'))
```

Comment: it is giving the error : 'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: odd concat is a SQL server function... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql  you could just change `concat(t.[internet_Order_Reference],'-RF-*')` to `t.[internet_Order_Reference] & '-RF-*'`

Comment: I have replaced and replaced & with + as it was giving error. It is executed but can not see any rows except headers.

Comment: I had a typo are you using % or *? Should be % for wildcard.

Comment: I have used % . Thank you